# While updating .docx file using docx4j, Read only fields become editable

Tags: docx, docx4j

In my `docx` file we have some readonly fields but, While i'm updating `docx` file using `docx4j` library that read only fields become editable.

XML Block

[image]

In document we have some section and readonly block for guide the user and below that section we have added block for enter value.

[image]

Dependency

```
compile "org.docx4j:docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl:8.3.4"
```

Comment: Please update your question adding the XML for one of the fields in question.

Comment: @JasonPlutext I have added XML and actual doc block. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Word, Review > Restrict Editing > Editing Restrictions > Filling in Forms
results in the following in the Document Settings part, word/settings.xml:

```
 <w:documentProtection w:edit="forms" w:enforcement="1"/>
```

Check this value before and after manipulation with docx4j.

If it is changing, then something in your code is changing it.

Basically you want something like:

```
DocumentSettingsPart documentSettingsPart = getPkg().getMainDocumentPart().getDocumentSettingsPart();

documentSettingsPart.protectRestrictEditing(STDocProtect.FORMS, null, null);
```

See further https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_11_4_7/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/DocumentSettingsPart.java#L311

Comment: Appreciate you ans but is not working for me. Can you please help me with the sample working demo ?

Comment: Did you check the value before and after manipulation with docx4j?